# Copy to clipboard not working in Android 9.0 (Pie)

Tags: android, copy, paste, android-9.0-pie

I am using the following code to copy the text to clipboard in my app.

```
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("ABC", "qwerty");
clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
```

Its working fine in Android 8.1 and below but its not working in Android 9.0 pie.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.!

Comment: using the same code for 9.0, works fine at my end. device info ?

Comment: @Sahil I have a OnePlus 6 device

Comment: @rahul Did found the solution?

Comment: With the latest update on my device it works fine now. Also tested on other devices it work fine.